# How to find the indefinite integral of $\int \frac{x^2}{x^2-2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am not sure i formatted it right but I was studying for calculus and came across a problem I couldn't compute.

$$\int \frac{x^2}{x^2-2}dx$$

I have not learned partial fractions yet so if this is a case where that is used, the techniques might not work for me.

What I have tried.  to do integration by parts, and substitution.  I put the denominator to the -1 power.  I got 1/2ln|x^2-2|*3/2x^3 but I am certain that isn't right.

Comment: Please show us some effort. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Hint: You can do long division of $x^2$ divided by $x^2-2$ and use partial fractions to simplify the remainder over $x^2-2$.

Comment: Before you can use partial fractions you need to do the long division to get a _proper_ fraction (where the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator). Here that amounts to noting that $\frac{x^2}{x^2-2}=\frac{x^2-2}{x^2-2}+\frac{2}{x^2-2}$.

Comment: I try to bring the denominator and then solve by substition for u=x^2-2 but then I still have that second x^2 on top.  I thought about long devision but didn't bother trying to be honest.  I know somewhere I'll get a natural log but not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1 :**

Put , $x=\sqrt 2\sec \theta$. Then , $\,dx=\sqrt 2 \sec\theta \tan \theta$.

**Hint 2:**

$\frac{x^2}{x^2-2}=1+\frac{2}{x^2-2}$

Comment: That second hint is what I was thinking about last night.  Can you tell me how you got it?

Comment: @chamburger Because $x^2  = x^2 - 2 + 2$, so
$$
\frac{x^2}{x^2 - 2} = \frac{x^2 - 2 + 2}{x^2 - 2} = \frac{x^2 - 2}{x^2 - 2} + \frac2{x^2 - 2}
$$

Comment: @Arthur I pulled up the 2.  to get 1/(x^2-1) i compute that now I used substitution.  i end up with x+ln|x^2-1|+C.  Does that seem right?

Answer (score 0):

Use partial fraction method.
Add and subtract 2 in the numerator and then the integration boggs down tona simple integration.